# Botão dropdown dentro de um card não funciona (Bootstrap/Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Olá, pessoal! Tudo bem?

Não consigo fazer o dropdown funcionar e abrir suas opções. Este botão está dentro de um card que é pra ser uma espécie de sidebar left. Peguei esse botão no bootstrap. Todo esse código está dentro de um card e uma nav. As dependencias jquery, popper estão baixadas.

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle  texto font-weight-bold icone mr-1" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/3190/3190426.svg" alt="" width="30" height="26"
            class="d-inline-block align-top">
         Ano Escolar
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1º ano EM</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2º ano EM</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3º ano EM</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle  texto font-weight-bold icone" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2702/2702162.svg" alt="" width="30" height="26"
            class="d-inline-block align-top mr-1">
        Matéria
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Português</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">História</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Matemática</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando "data-bs-toggle", que é um atributo do Bootstrap 5.

Ou você remove o "data-bs-toggle" e substitui por apenas "data-toggle", ou você migra o site para Bootstrap 5.